# softlayer API : SoftLayer_Account_Lockdown_Request's reconnectCompute method

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

i am testing SoftLayer_Account_Lockdown_Request API

i completed a test of disconnectComputeTest() method.

disconnectComputeTest finish a power and disconnect Public&Private Network link.

next,

I tested reconnectComputeTest() method.
During check for a test result, i found that reconnectCompute() method's work is wrong.

server power on - OK

Private network on - OK

Public network off - Not OK

I tested several times, but the results are the same.

why don't the Public network link connect?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to submit a ticket in the control portal because according documentation all the public networks should be reconnected, it seems that you are facing an issue.